# The 'lang' selector for css is not working in gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, mailchimp, lang

I'm using a * [lang~=x-divbox] selector for designing a newsletter (mailchimp) that will work in gmail (table of content)

**I worked out a solution in my old template that still works**, but when I use it in my new template it's not working: here's the code I'm using and screenshot comparison (and it is identical):

```
* [lang~=x-divbox]{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#939598;

    }
    * [lang~=x-divbox] h2{
        /*@editable*/color:#fffffe!important;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
    }
    * [lang~=x-divbox] ul{
        /*@editable*/margin:0 !important;
        /*@editable*/padding:0 !important;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
    }
    * [lang~=x-divbox] li{
        /*@editable*/margin:0 !important;
        /*@editable*/padding:0 !important;
        /*@editable*/list-style-type:none !important;
        /*@editable*/color:#fffffe !important;
    }
    * [lang~=x-divbox] a{
        /*@editable*/display:block !important;
        /*@editable*/padding:10px 0 !important;
        /*@editable*/color:#fffffe !important;
        /*@editable*/text-decoration:none;
        border-bottom:1px solid #fffffe !important;
    }
```

The html part:

```
     <tr>
<td><a name="top"></a></td></tr>
```

In this issue...

    *|MC:TOC|*

it's not allowing me to post the full code here:

[image]

This is how it should be working:

[image]

And this is how it looks now:

[image]

I don't know what else I'm supposed to be looking at.

All I know it's like google is ignoring the lang in one case.

This is what is see's in the working example:

[image]

And this is what it sees for the not working one (no mentioning of the selector):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @media queries in your **style**, Gmail blocks the whole CSS. Try only containing the [lang] CSS you need in a separate **style**, it might do the trick.